# Utilisation de d'environ contre environ

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, attributs

In my duolingo exercises I am seeing “La distance est d'environ deux kilomètres” and "La durée est environ une heure”. When do you decide to use d'environ or simply environ?

Comment: "Environ" plays no role in this : this is between saying simply "La distance est de deux kilomètres." or "La distance est deux kilomètres". And quite frankly, as a native, this is a damn good question.

Comment: +1 @MadWard. And « La durée est environ une heure » seems quite weird too. I would have put « d' ».

Comment: @Larme You mean "d'environ une heure" or "environ d'une heure" ? I think both are ok...

Comment: @Random Both are okay, and even "d'une heure environ".

Comment: @Random “environ d'une heure” is not idiomatic to my ears, nor to Google Books.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*de* (or *d'*) is not part of the expression '*environ*'.

> La distance est **d'environ** deux kilomètres.
>
> La distance est **environ** **de** deux kilomètres.
>
> La distance est **de** deux kilomètres **environ**.

Or just:

> La distance est **de** deux kilomètres.

So the question is more why we use *de*. Honnestly, I couldn't say why.

Answer (score 2):

***Environ :***

- Préposition : *Dans le voisinage de , aux alentours* ; synonymes : *vers*.
- Adverbe devant un nombre : *À peu près, un peu plus un peu moins* ; synonymes : *approximativement, en gros*.

La position d'*environ* est à prendre en compte, et les usages selon que cela concerne le lieu ou le temps :

> Une distance ***d'environ*** deux kilomètres.
> Une distance ***de*** deux kilomètres ***environ***.
>
> La durée est ***d'environ*** une heure.
> La durée est ***d***'une heure ***environ***.
>
> Tu arriveras ***aux environs d***'une heure l'après-midi =
> Tu arriveras *vers* une heure de l'après-midi.
> Cela ce passera ***aux environs de*** Noël.
>
> On cultive les fleurs ***dans les environs de*** Grasse pour la parfumerie.

N.B. :

Si l'on *qualifie* la distance par sa longueur :

- la distance *d* est applicable entre ces deux points.
- Approximativement, la distance 'Paris-Strasbourg' (à l'écrit on utilisera plutôt : de Paris à Strasbourg) est équivalente à (celle de) 'Paris-La Rochelle'.

Si l'on *quantifie* la distance :

- La distance qui sépare ces deux points est *de* trois kilomètres.
- Il nous faut parcourir une distance *de* trois kilomètres pour arriver au but.

---

<sup>*Références puisées dans le petit Robert*.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The presence (or not) of the adverb *environ* is unrelated to the use of the preposition. You say “*d'environ une heure*” if you would say “*d'une heure*” for an exact number.

> La durée est d'une heure.
>   La durée est d'environ une heure.
>   La durée est d'exactememt une heure.
>   La durée est de plus d'une heure.
>   La durée est d'entre une heure et une heure et demie.

The location of some of these adverbs can vary, for example “*d'une heure environ*”, “*d'une heure exactement*”. The two word orders are equally common and idiomatic, and I don't think there's a nuance in their meaning.

This is a construction of the verb *être* when expressing a quantity with a numerical amount and usually a unit. The [*Trésor de la langue française*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%AAtre) classifies it under 2<sup>e</sup>I.B.6.a “To express the origin, the provenance, conformation to a model, and by extension an apparent or inherent characteristic of someone or something or membership in a group”.

> Être constitué, composé de. *Son capital est de trois cent mille francs; le délai est de quatre jours; le nombre officiel des victimes est de quatre-vingts.*